# Magnific - passing variable javascript issue

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, magnific-popup

When a link is clicked on my page, it displays an alert with the ID of the item in question. But the next thing that happens (popup triggered with URL + querystring containing that ID), displays as undefined. So I'm just trying to figure out why the variable ID is not holding the value when the popup is called.

**Edit:** So now with the current changes, it requires 2 clicks to get the popup to display with the correct querystring/ID. Any ideas? When changing .magnificPopup to .magnificPopup.open it fails to do anything onclick.

**Edit:** Now its working. Fixed line with: $.magnific.open to remove the class name that was tied to it. Everything works perfect now. Thanks for the help!

```
<head><meta charset='UTF-8'> 

<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css'>
</head><body>   
<script src='magnific-popup/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>
<script src='magnific-popup/magnific-popup.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.simple-ajax-popup2').click(function () {
            ID = $(this).data("var1");
           // alert(""+ID+"");
            $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: 'Test.html?ID='  + ID + '' 
            },
            type: 'iframe',
        });
        }); 


    });
</script>
<a class="simple-ajax-popup2" data-var1="1" href='#' >
    test 1
</a> <br>
<a class="simple-ajax-popup2" data-var1="2" href='#' >
   test 2
</a> <br>
<a class="simple-ajax-popup2" data-var1="3" href='#' >
   test 3
</a> 
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call your popup within the click event's function, otherwise, by the time magnificPopup is executed, ID is still undefined:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.simple-ajax-popup2').click(function () {

          ID = $(this).data("var1");
          alert(""+ID+"");
          $('.simple-ajax-popup2').magnificPopup.open({
               items: {
                   src: 'Test.aspx?ID='  + ID + "" 
               },
               type: 'iframe',
           });
      });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but still seems that something is wrong. First time clicking the link, the alert shows and nothing else happens. 2nd attempt to click the link it appears to work correct. But then when clicking other items on the page (same link but different ID/Item), it seems to always be loading the value from the previous link, not the currently clicked one.

Comment: So it basically takes 2 clicks to achieve the correct action. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you test the code that I edited, and that is still happening?

Comment: Yes, that is the result of the code you posted. First click launches an alert with the current value, but doesnt trigger the popup. 2nd attempt to click works properly. But its loading the previous clicks value.

Comment: ok, I don't have your whole code, but I've removed the unnecessary global variable and used the modal's open method to see if it opens on the first try

Comment: Actually... I thought I had it working but it appears not so. Its still requiring two clicks to get to the correct ID. And I tried with your suggestion of .magnificPopup.open, which seemed to fail. Not sure where to go from here. The issue seems to be consistent in both IE and chrome.

Comment: Here is the dumbed down version (see original post)

Comment: You should replace single quotes with double quotes on data-var1='3'

Comment: They were single cause it was being populated from a DB. I switched back for the sake of this sample code, still not working properly.

Comment: I just tried to apply an edit to your code to block the alert and slightly adjust the syntax on the popup open call. Its working now.  

This line:  $('.simple-ajax-popup2').magnificPopup({
Needed to be: $.magnificPopup.open({